# Visio 2007 - how to export ERD to sqlserver schema

Tags: visual-studio, visio

I've hit a minor brick wall here in Visio. I've got a project that I'm running that's hosted under sqlserver and is subject to lots of model changes in Visio 2007 (via a 3rd party).

The problem for me is that due to visio 2007 not allowing me to export the ERD (supplied by the 3rd party), I have to scan the model and manually update the database with the new/amended properties. As you can imagine, not a task for the faint hearted, especially as the table count has gone beyond 50 in this section. I'd dearly love to be able to just 'forward engineer to SQL' at the click of a button.

Now, I realise that visio 2003 and the "Visio Enterprise Architect" versions did allow this, however, I'm just on plain Visio professional 2007, so that option isn't available to me. I did also see a few suggestions on the internet to get around this issue but neither were suitable for my uses:

visio 2010 only (therfore not suitable)

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2010/04/16/visio-forward-engineer-addin-for-office-2010.aspx

visio 2003 with .net 1.1. framework - hmmm

http://blog.donnfelker.com/2007/05/11/simplifying-database-modeling-in-visio-20022003-through-sql-generation/

I'm 'imagining' an addin that someone may have created that will hook into 2007.

Fingers xx'd - any thoughts??

**[edit] -** i actually got it working via the Orthoganol Toolbox as per link above. just a matter of installing .net 1.1 (yikes) and it all works fine. Rather then delete the question, I'll leave as is in case anyone else has a similar need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the answer, see my edit above re .net 1.1 installation and the Orthoganol Toolbox link.

not pretty but got me out of a jam.