# Exporting Visio 2010 Database Diagram to Erwin

Tags: export, visio, erd, erwin

I have an ERD in MS Visio 2010 64-bit Edition. I would like to get the diagram into CA Erwin 7.3.

Ideally, I'd like to find something that exports from Visio into a format that Erwin understands (I've read a lot about ERX - Visio doesn't seem to export itself, but there was mention of a Visio add-in that can, but I can't find it).

I also wouldn't mind forward-engineering the model to a database and then reverse-engineering it into Erwin. I tried the first link in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670502/visio-2007-how-to-export-erd-to-sqlserver-schema), but unfortunately THAT add-in doesn't work with Visio 2010 64-bit!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ERwin R7 has the feature to import Microsoft Visio UML V 1.x XMI
I am not a Visio but an ERwin guy so.  Best to check whetehr you can export you vision model to VISIO UML  and then we can import it using ERwin R7.3.

To do this.
Start Erwin R7.3, got to File Import from External sources, from the pull down bar, choose Microsoft list of importable tools (Visio is one of them) or as you mentioned Vision ERX format.